# How to find x and y-offset for slider in python for a web-application

Tags: python, webdriver

Can anyone please tell me how to find the x-offset and y-offset default value of a Slider in a webpage using python for selenium webdriver.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get_attribute(name) method on a webelement to retrieve attributes.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer ...Atually I have a slider in a webpage and its default position is at 0 , say i have to move it to position 5 how to move it to this 

position.Currently im using the method move_by_offset(x-offset,y-offset) but not able to know how to give the values as it 

behaves randomly..